# List Categories AND their associated entries

Tags: entries, categories

I'm trying to create a category driven gallery. My setup (right or wrong) is this:-

Users create a new entry within a Structure, title it, add photos and then assign the entry to a pre-defined gallery category.

My idea is that when a visitor lands on the 'Gallery' page they see a 'grid' of latest photos (this is a question which might appear here later), with a navigation on the side which allows them to browse the other galleries (categories).

So, how do I list out the categories and associated entries for this navigation?

Example:

- Category Title One

  - Title of the entry1
  - Title of the entry2
  - Title of the entry3
- Category Title Two

  - Title of the entry4
  - Title of the entry5
- Category Title Three

  - Title of the entry6
  - Title of the entry7
  - Title of the entry8
- Category Title Four

  - Title of the entry9

I don't want the Category Titles to be links, just the entries within them.

I hope this makes sense and someone can provide a solution.

Many thanks

Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along the line of this should do that:

```
<ul>
    {% for category in craft.categories.group('categoryGroupHandle') %}
    <li>
        {{ category.title }}
        {% for entry in craft.entries.section('sectionHandle').relatedTo(category) %}
            {% if loop.first %}<ul>{% endif %}
                <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
            {% if loop.last %}</ul>{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Probably some bugs in here, but should be enough to get you started.

Also probably smart to wrap this in `{% cache %}` tags, as it probably will trigger a lot of database queries.

Comment: Brilliant! Many thanks for this.  I also managed to get it working with a definition list which felt more semantic for my purposes.